# Populate local div with external script results

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working with Angular and JQuery on a site, and set the header and footer as partials in order to maximize re-use.  The issue I have is that I need some javascript to be handled within the footer upon load, but that is not supported by Angular via the `ng-include` tag or JQuery with the `$.load()` method.

I have multiple 3rd party scripts that I want to run, but the one I'm working on right now is one of those Verisign scripts which returns an image, which is loaded using the `<script src=""></script>` pattern.  I know that at least presently there is no way for Javascript to pull in external scripts, so my thought was to simply create a container div where I want the image to appear, to run the 3rd party script from the main page, and to then take that content and populate the container div via reference, conceptually looking like this:

```
//footer.html
<div id="siteVerify"></div>

//index.html
//call a method that takes 3rd party that i can point to siteVerify
```

Is it possible to point that 3rd party script to the siteVerify div without having the script run inside the div?

Conversely, if there is an alternative preferred method for html code re-use so that I can simply edit changes in one place and have them propegate throughout the site?

edit:

I put:

```
// If you know these dead scripts will be in a certain container, refine your jQuery selector
$(document).ready(function(){

// If you know these dead scripts will be in a certain container, refine your jQuery selector
    $('.deadScriptContainer script').each(function(){
        // If a script has content, we want to execute it
        if($(this).html().length > 0){
            // Eval() will execute any JavaScript it is passed
            eval($(this).html());
        }else{
            // If this script has no content, let's see if it has a src
            if($(this).src){
                // Create a new script tag
                var newScript = document.createElement("script");
                newScript.type = "text/javascript";
                newScript.src = $(this).src;
                // Append new script to the head
                document.querySelector("head").appendChild(newScript);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

into a js file, and call it at the bottom of my index.html file.  Meanwhile in my footer, I have something like this:

```
<div class='deadScriptContainer'><span id='siteseal'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=...."></script></span>
</div>
```

so it should be finding the script tag within the div with the class 'deadScriptContainer', and looking up its src, which should be the https:....  I put an alert in the code and it indeed appears to be finding the script tag, but when i check to see what the src value is, it always returns 'undefined'.

I have a feeling my selectors are probably wrong, but I can't see what it is about them.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but are you basically having an issue with when you load in new data from ajax, there are `<script>` tags in that new data and those tags aren't firing when you put them on the page? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: that's the underlying issue, yes.  I would either need the script to be evaluated upon loading the partial, or to run it from the main page and take the content and populate the markup in the partial.  From everything I've read, there is no support to evaluate <script> tags on loading partials

Comment: See my answer and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load in script tags using AJAX, the problem is they're brought in as *placed* where you want it, hence why it doesn't fire. There is an easy way to revive these dead scripts though, so you're in luck!

Once you have your data back from your AJAX request, evaluate any internal JavaScript.

For external JavaScript, what you need to do is create a new `<script>` tag and give it the dead script's source.

The entire process should look something like this once you've loaded in your new data:

```
// If you know these dead scripts will be in a certain container, refine your jQuery selector
$('deadScriptContainer script').each(function(){
    // If a script has content, we want to execute it
    if($(this).html().length > 0){
        // Eval() will execute any JavaScript it is passed
        eval($(this).html());
    }else{
        // If this script has no content, let's see if it has a src
        if($(this).src){
            // Create a new script tag
            var newScript = document.createElement("script");
            newScript.type = "text/javascript";
            newScript.src = $(this).src;
            // Append new script to the head
            document.querySelector("head").appendChild(newScript);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so with this process i would add a class attribute for each script called "deadScriptContainer" ?

Comment: That container is basically where the dead scripts are. So for example, if you load in all the new data to some div, you want to target all the script tags from that div.

Comment: ok so i'm putting the scripts in a container tagged 'deadScriptContainer' and it will look inside and find any scripts to be handled

Comment: Well just target where your dead scripts are basically. "DeadScriptContainer" is arbitrary

Comment: right, i'm saying based upon your example, not necessarily that it has to be called 'deadscriptcontainer'

Comment: Correct. We want to target every script that is dead

Comment: and ideally should I throw a document.ready around it to make sure that the container has actually been loaded

Comment: looks like it's finding local scripts which is good, still having issues with external script.  i put an alert in there to show when it's hitting the code to evaulate the src but i'm not seeing the actual result appear

Comment: I did a couple alerts and it looks like it's returning undefined, will edit my question to show what i'm seeing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97236/discussion-between-nick-z-and-david-torrey).